# Exponential equation with one 'trouble' term

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation:

$4^{2x} - 12 * 4^{x} + 32 = 0$

But this $12$ doesn't make me able to have all terms in the same base, how to proceed with it ?

Comment: The equation is quadratic in $4^x$.

Comment: So for a hint set $y=4^x$ and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

Let $4^x = a $,  then
$a^2 - 12a +32 = 0$.
Solving the quadratic equation we get 
$(a-4)(a-8) = 0$; or $ a = 4 $ or $ a = 8$. Hence,
$4^x = 4$ ; $x = 1$.
if a = 8 then 
$4^x = 8 $
; $(2^2)^x = 2 ^3$
; 2x = 3 ; x = 1.5

Answer (score 1):

Two Hints here :

Set $y=4^x$ and it will become a quadratic.

And avoid the negative solution if any . ( Guess why ? )

Answer (score 0):

Let be $4^x = w$, and solve equation in $w$.